# selecting best time series collection to predict a given time series

Tags: time-series, correlation, prediction, feature-selection

I have a relatively large collection of time series (approximately 100) and I need to use them to predict future values of a specific one of them, at different time horizons.

Before even thinking about possible predictive models, I'd like to trim the number of time series down to something more "manually explorable" (say ten to fifteen). Moreover, potentially few of these time series will have no correlation at all with my target time series, so I want to make sure I only keep the relevant ones: those which will have some sort of predictive power.

Is there some sort of "good practice" for this task?

The first thing I thought of is that I might simply look at individual correlations between each of the time series and appropriate lags of my target variable. Does this make sense at all?
It seems a little fiddly to me, and I'm sure there are more robust ways to do so.

Any help in this direction would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!